# Check if PK in XML file is similar to PK in Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, xml, database

**Using C# .Net**

I have made a program which export Tables from SQL server database to XML files.
Then I will make changes to the XML file and import it back to the DB.

My new program which im currently working on shall check my XML file and compare it to the same table on the DB. If primary key is the same on XML file as on the DB it will delete the row in the XML file, rest of the rows with different PK will get imported.

I am using SqlBulkCopy to import tables from XML to the DB. 
The problem is that I dont know how to get the primary key from XML and compare it to the primary key on DB.

Sample XML structure:

```
<NewDataSet> 
    <Table>
      <DeviceId>1</DeviceId>
      <DeviceTypeId>1</DeviceTypeId>
      <Disabled>false</Disabled>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Post the XML, and what you've tried so far

Comment: <NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <DeviceId>1</DeviceId>
    <DeviceTypeId>1</DeviceTypeId>
    <Disabled>false</Disabled>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>

The XML could look something like this where DeviceTypeId could be PK. Ive tried using "DataTable.PrimaryKey Property". But i just dont get things working. I dont know how i should obtain the value of the primary key from the XML and the DB

Comment: Thanks, you need to look into [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) - see my answer for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an XML structure of:

```
<NewDataSet> 
   <Table>
     <DeviceId>1</DeviceId>
     <DeviceTypeId>1</DeviceTypeId>
     <Disabled>false</Disabled>
   </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

You could use a simple [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) query to get the `DeviceId` (PK) from the XML:

```
var id = (from n in xml.Root.Elements("Table")
          select n.Element("DeviceId").Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

Returns: `1`

Edit* If each of your tables have a different column name for the PK then you would need to rewrite this or write data access code specific for each table:

```
public static int GetTablePK(string identifier)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32((from n in xml.Root.Elements("Table")
          select n.Element(indentifier).Value).SingleOrDefault());
}
```

Where `identifier` is the PK name. This assumes a similar XML structure for the tables

Comment: Well, im looping through 1000+ tables. Is it possible to get the primary key without writting it manually?

Comment: `Is it possible to get the primary key without writting it manually?` - what?

Comment: Well, now you are selecting "deviceId" as Element. Because you know it is the Primary key, but what if you have 1000 tables. And you dont have the time to write each PrimaryKey Elements.

Comment: Are you saying that the primary key node name will be different for each table? If this is the case then you are pretty much screwed

Comment: You'll need to write separate data access methods for each table type, or if the table structure is always the same and only the PK name changes then you can just pass in the node name as a string to a generic function